# how to handle ngClass in stencils JS web components

Tags: javascript, stencils

I have made components in angular js 4,  now i am trying to make the same component as a web components in stencils Js.

I have the angular code as below

```html
<button [class]="classNames" (click)="toggleMasterButton()" 
[ngClass]="masterButtonActive ? _config.masterButtonClass :'-state-grey'">
```

I tried the code as below but unable to go resolve the ngClass and class properly as in the angular component. Any help will be appreciated.

```html
<button  onClick={this.toggleMasterButton.bind(this)}
class={this.masterButtonActive ? this._config.masterButtonClass:'-state-grey'}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to update/toggle `css` class when the user clicks on the button.

To update class which you want to reflect on UI, in stencils-js you need to decorate with `@State`

You can read more about  [stenciljs.com doc](https://stenciljs.com/docs/decorators)

In short, you need to update your code as below.

```
 import { State } from '@stencil/core';

 export class TodoList {

  @State() masterButtonActive:boolean = false;


   toggleMasterButton(){
        this.masterButtonActive= true;
     }

      render() {
        <button  onClick={this.toggleMasterButton.bind(this)}
           class={'mcf__btn ' + ( this.masterButtonActive ? this.config.masterButtonClass:   '-state-grey')}My button</button>
        }
   }
```

Hope this will work for you.